# Set value of all the rows based on the value of another row in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an input dataframe with values:

```
|sequence|company_number|errorCode|errorType|isDropped|
+--------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 9999999|      XXXXXXXX| OADL0002|   FILERJ|        N|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0003|       RJ|        Y|
|    8487|      XXXXXXXX| OADL0004|       RJ|        Y|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0006|       RJ|        Y|
|    8486|      ZZZZZZZZ| OADL0007|       RJ|        Y|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0005|       RJ|        Y|
|    8486|      ZZZZZZZZ| OADL0008|       RJ|        Y|
```

I want to set the value of another column `Dropped` based on the value of `errorType`. If `errorType` is `FILERJ` in any row, then set the `Dropped` to `Y` for all the rows.

Output Dataframe:

```
|sequence|company_number|errorCode|errorType|isDropped|Dropped|
+--------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 9999999|      XXXXXXXX| OADL0002|   FILERJ|        N|      Y|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0003|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
|    8487|      XXXXXXXX| OADL0004|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0006|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
|    8486|      ZZZZZZZZ| OADL0007|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
|    8487|      YYYYYYYY| OADL0005|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
|    8486|      ZZZZZZZZ| OADL0008|       RJ|        Y|      Y|
```

Comment: And what if the value `FILTERJ` exists nowhere in the column `errorType` ?

Comment: @Timeless Then `Dropped` must be set to `N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
df.withColumn("asNo", F.when(F.col("errorCode") == "FILERJ", 1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn("asNo", F.sum(F.col("asNo")).over(Window.orderBy(F.lit("dummy"))))\
.withColumn("Dropped", F.when(F.col("asNo") > 0, F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+---------+-------+
|errorCode|Dropped|
+---------+-------+
|   FILERJ|      N|
|       RJ|      Y|
|       RJ|      Y|
|       RJ|      Y|
+---------+-------+
```

Output (Keeping the intermediate column for understanding, you can drop):

```
+---------+-------+----+
|errorCode|Dropped|asNo|
+---------+-------+----+
|   FILERJ|      Y|   1|
|       RJ|      Y|   1|
|       RJ|      Y|   1|
|       RJ|      Y|   1|
+---------+-------+----+
```